# Why I am getting "oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleResultSetImpl@3ee82600" value in ResultSet instead Userid and password

Tags: java, jdbc

I've the below DAO method:

```
    public boolean validate(String UserName,String password) throws Exception
    {
        this.userName=UserName;
        this.password=password;


        boolean status=false;
        PreparedStatement pst = null;
        ResultSet rs = null; 
        Connection con = null;  
        DataBase db =new DataBase();
        con=db.dbConnection();
        User user=new User();
        try {
            pst=con.prepareStatement("select * from login where userId=? and password=?");
            pst.setString(1, user.getUserName());
            pst.setString(2, user.getPassword());
        } catch (SQLException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            rs=pst.executeQuery();
            System.out.println("Result in  Resultset"+rs);
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            while(rs.next())
            {
                if((rs.getString("USERID")==user.getUserName()) && (rs.getString("Password")==user.getPassword()))
                {           
                    status=true;
                }
                else
                {
                    status=false;
                }
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.println("Data is not store in result set");
            e.printStackTrace();


    }
        return status;

}
```

[image]

so here is the problem I am facing in the image I am getting this-"oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleResultSetImpl@3ee82600" value in ResultSet object rs, instead of userid and password from my database

Comment: And this folks is an example of how to leak resources when working with JDBC

Comment: Thanks at least I got some idea from above comment that i need to close the connection and instead of using == I should use equals.

Comment: I really don't understand. why people are so rude instead of being helpful people are busy in earning bounty..I have just started learning jsp and servlet and I really dont have knowledge how to write optimize code and how things work. some time I feel posting a question on stack overflow is like being victim.

Comment: I would advise focusing on one area at a time - the JSP/Servlet API is not really the place to start with Java IMHO.  The problem you're seeing above is because your IDE is introspecting the `Connection` object using reflection and doing a `toString` on it (`toString` hasn't be overridden  and so the default implementation is being used).  I would suggest some basic Java and JDBC tutorials first

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the values of `Userid` and `password` by doing

```
if(rs.next()) {
    String userId = rs.getString("userId");
    String password = rs.getString("password");
}
```

Comment: I have done the same thing in LoginDao but its not working

Comment: You are trying to get value of `"USERID"` but your column name in Database table is `"userId"`.Same goes for `password`. You are using `"Password" ` but database column name is `"password"`. Also you are comparing string using `==` which won't work in Java as `String` is a reference in Java. Use `.equals()` instead.

Comment: I have tried what you say. but when I am debug-in my code and when control reaches to if(rs.next) it is spiking the if loop and rs has "oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleResultSetImpl@5577f5b5" value. my question is that it should have the db value or null. please respond

Comment: Please show your `import statements` of `LoginDao.java`.

Comment: import java.io.*;
import java.sql.*;

Comment: The `ResultSet` object `rs` which has a value `oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleResultSetImpl@5577f5b5` indicates that the object is **NOT** `null`. It tells that the object is of class `oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleResultSetImpl` with hashcode `5577f5b5`. If you execute `System.out.println(rs);` then `oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleResultSetImpl@5577f5b5` will get printed.

Comment: This happens because the `toString()` method of class `oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleResultSetImpl` is overridden to print the class name and the hash code. But, to access the values, i.e., `userId` and `password`, you can follow my answer.